# How to create an incrementing name for each item (radio input) in a foreach loop

Tags: mysql, forms, foreach, radio-button, rename

I have a questionnaire that needs to increment the name of the radio type questions. Whenever I try to do this and subsequently upload to MySQL it says I have an undefined index.

```
foreach ($surveyquestion as $question) {
                    echo "<b>$question</b> <br>";   
                    echo "<input type='radio' name='answers[qa_checklist]' value='yes' /> Yes";
                    echo "<input type='radio' name='answers[qa_checklist]' value='no' /> No";

                    echo "<br><br>";
                }

$sql = 'INSERT INTO qasurveychecklist ( `question`, `qa_checklist`) VALUES(     null, ?)';

    // prepare the query for binding to the placeholders later on
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare( $sql );

    // bind some variables to the placeholders
    $stmt->mysqli_stmt_bind_param( 'si', $qa_checklist );

        // loop through all date values
        foreach( $answers[ 'qa_checklist' ] as $key => $value )
            {

            // give the previously bound variables values for this query execution
            $qa_checklist = $answers[ 'qa_checklist' ][ $key ];

            // execute it!
            $stmt->exec();
```

Comment: My HTML code is not the problem, and I use an isset($_POST['submit']) to enter into the SQL insertion. I'm just have a lot of trouble understanding how I can make a new name for 20 different yes/no questions so that I can store 20 yes/no answers into MySQL. Thank you for the help, I am very new to php and mysql